# MySQL import taking a long time to finish/ never ends

Tags: mysql

My ~700mb database has been importing for 1hr 27min now, the actual disk activity stopped at around 15min but I just left it running to see if it would finish by itself.

The command I ran:

```
mysqldump DB1 | pv | mysql DB2
```

So it's pretty much a straight copy from 1 database to another, with `DB2` starting as empty.

I can actually see that the data is already in `DB2`, but the command refuses to end!

So the question is... Should I let it continue to run? Or can I kill it? :/

Updated:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;

+------+--------------+---------------------+------------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id   | User         | Host                | db         | Command | Time | State  | Info                                                                                                 |
+------+--------------+---------------------+------------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2762 | user1        | localhost           | DB2        | Query   | 5298 | Locked | /*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50020 DEFINER="user2"@"%"*/ /*!50003 FUNCTION "function1"                       |
| 2763 | user1        | localhost           | DB1        | Sleep   | 5298 |        | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 2770 | user2        | localhost           | NULL       | Query   | 3633 | Locked | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`ROUTINES` WHERE `ROUTINE_SCHEMA`='DB2' AND `ROUTIN        |
| 2775 | user2        | localhost           | NULL       | Query   |  381 | Locked | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`ROUTINES` WHERE `ROUTINE_SCHEMA`='DB2' AND `ROUTIN        |
| 2776 | user2        | <ipaddress>:<port>  | NULL       | Query   |    0 | NULL   | show processlist                                                                                     |
+------+--------------+---------------------+------------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Some settings I have that are non-standard:

```
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

Comment: What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` on DB2 say is going on?

Comment: @lxg `pv` is a command utility, I'm using it to monitor the pipe between `mysqldump` and `mysql`

Comment: @tadman updated question with additional info